# Making that Admin Bar transparent or a blue color

Tags: plugins, themes, css, admin-bar

The question title is pretty self-explanatory - I don't really like the new Admin's bar's colour but I find it useful and want to keep it so I would like to change the colour of it. However, I'm not the best at web scripting, let alone CSS so I wondered if anybody here would help me to make the Admin Bar the following sort of  HEX color:  #62BACE.

If that color isn't really possible, or it is easier - I wouldn't mind having a transparent admin bar!

Any assistance would be very kind and grately appreciated!

Thanks in advance

PS If there's a plugin that does this for me I wouldn't mind using it - I just don't know of any and can't code in CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good plugin to make the admin bar blue in both the admin and front-end: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blue-admin-bar/

If those colors don't suit, play around with the plugin to figure out how to do your own. The key thing to notice about the plugin version is that by using a hook to enqueue the stylesheets, it's possible to get the dashboard version as well -- adding to your theme's css will only affect the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this to your styles.css:

```
#wpadminbar {
    background-color:#62BACE !important;
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(bottom,#62BACE,#6291cc 5px) !important;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom,#62BACE,#6291cc 5px) !important;
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(bottom,#62BACE,#6291cc 5px) !important;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,from(#62BACE ),to(#6291cc)) !important;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,#62BACE,#6291cc 5px) !important;
    background-image:linear-gradient(bottom,#62BACE,#6291cc 5px) !important;
}
```

You will need to also style the anchor colors and stuff, but that will make the bar blue. You can change the colors how you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, but like I said - I really don't know CSS and when you hover over some parts, it still turns grey etc. I'm sorry but I'm really quite lost here. Thanks for your answer though - I hope you can provide me with some further code/help...

Comment: Looking into it a bit further, it's more complicated. The normal place you would put the styles (Since you aren't supposed to touch anything outside of your theme) doesn't get loaded in the admin panel. You would need add a PHP function to initialize it on the admin panel before you could even start restyling the admin bar. Additionally, the admin bar could change, meaning your styles could stop working at some point (the menu has been updated twice this year already). Without understanding all this, what you are asking for is a risky change and you should probably just disable the menu.

Comment: I thought that would be the case from the lack of information online. As you can see I have accepted @sabreuse's answer because the plugin he mentioned does almost exactly what I need but stops me from having to encounter what you have mentioned in your previous comment etc. Thank you anyway - I appreciate your help!